# How to access the values from inner key of associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

Following is may multidimensional array named `$form_data`:

```
Array
(
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [teacher_id] => 3807f31f8c4357bbb56662047529dcde
    [cs_map_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 144
            [1] => 130
            [2] => 131
            [3] => 67
            [4] => 89
        )

    [btn_submit] => Done
)
```

I want to access only the values from key `[cs_map_ids]` using foreach loop. But couldn't access the values inside array `[cs_map_ids]`. Can anyone help me out on how should I access these values one by one using foreach loop? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what you have tried. Are you getting any error?

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q2b-tb3 , foreach works the same when foreach($array as $something) or foreach($array['arrayKey'] as $something)

Answer (score 5):

Should be quite straight forward, try

```
foreach($form_data['cs_map_ids'] as $map_id)
{
    echo $map_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($form_data['cs_map_ids'] as $d) echo "$d<br />";
```